# iOS 8 : How to open iTunes with given key words?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, nsurl, itunes-store

In my app i get the song iTunes link. When I tried to open that link in iOS 8 parentheses are adding to the keywords.
ex: If I pass the "http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?at=10lwW9&term=I+Will+Follow+Chris+Tomlin&country=US" ... then its opening the safari then iTunes and then in iTunes Parentheses are adding to the key workds. i.e the query becomes ( "I Will Follow Chris Tomlin" )... and in iOS 7 its not adding any parentheses and opening the iTunes for specified song details..

I have tried with changing http with itms still no luck...
my code

```html
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZSearch.woa/wa/search?at=10lwW9&term=I+Will+Follow+Chris+Tomlin&country=US"]];
```

Comment: https://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api.html

Comment: @Desdenova : I have read the document and checked every thing. Even i opened the url in safari (iOS 8) on device same thing is happening...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have found a solution with the help of following link...

[iOS open iTunes music search with given keywords from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26027416/ios-open-itunes-music-search-with-given-keywords-from-app)

To be short & precise ... We have to replace the "MZSearch" word in the url with "MZStore" that's all. It is working fine in iOS 7 & 8.